# Bootstrap select - scroll to selected value

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap select (http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) in my project and I want to achieve this: if I have many options in my select, whenever I open the menu, I want it to be scrolled somehow that my selected option is visible. Something like the select elements on http://jsfiddle.net/

Any ideea if that is possible?

Comment: Please provide jsfiddle link after saving the fiddle.

Comment: The link is http://jsfiddle.net/ , without saving. Look at the "select" elements on left :)